# Ruby on rails hosting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, hosting, ruby-on-rails-3

First Hello, **and then yearh i know Heroku!**

But they somehow just dosen't fit my interest, i want to have an email service. Well that's fine with heroku if you insert your credit card informations.. Well ya, no thank you.. So is there an alternative to Heroku? Or is it just imposible?

ohh.. by the way, i need crons, email and rails3 support :-)!

/Oluf Nielsen

Comment: What are your criteria?  Your dislike for entering credit card information sounds like you want an alternative free service?

Comment: Yearh, i think it's kinda impossible.. But i didn't want to enter my credit card information on Heroku.. But i don't think i find any thing good and free.. So as cheap as possible, and my criteria is on the second last line :-)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try find something in your country - then you don't need to leave your CC info and wire bank transfer should be enough. You will find at least VPS - which means DIY - not so hard actually if you know some Linux config stuff.